# Extract features from an arbitrary intermediate layer with VGG19

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to extract features from an arbitrary intermediate layer with VGG19 on kaggle with the following code and I'm getting errors. Don't know what the problem is

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg19 import VGG19
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg19 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
import numpy as np

base_model = VGG19(weights='imagenet')
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=base_model.get_layer('block4_pool').output)

img_path = '../input/dogs-vs-cats-redux-kernels-edition/train.zip'

img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(x)

block4_pool_features = model.predict(x)
```

It starts to download the data then stops and shows the following errors. I have other codes working fine before the above

```
gaierror                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1318                 h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
-> 1319                           encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
   1320             except OSError as err: # timeout error

URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-e2f0501f61ce> in <module>
      5 import numpy as np
      6 
----> 7 base_model = VGG19(weights='imagenet')
      8 model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=base_model.get_layer('block4_pool').output)
      9 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/applications/vgg19.py in VGG19(include_top, weights, input_tensor, input_shape, pooling, classes, classifier_activation)
    217           WEIGHTS_PATH,
    218           cache_subdir='models',
--> 219           file_hash='cbe5617147190e668d6c5d5026f83318')
    220     else:
    221       weights_path = data_utils.get_file(

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/data_utils.py in get_file(fname, origin, untar, md5_hash, file_hash, cache_subdir, hash_algorithm, extract, archive_format, cache_dir)
    280         raise Exception(error_msg.format(origin, e.code, e.msg))
    281       except URLError as e:
--> 282         raise Exception(error_msg.format(origin, e.errno, e.reason))
    283     except (Exception, KeyboardInterrupt) as e:
    284       if os.path.exists(fpath):

Exception: URL fetch failure on https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/keras-applications/vgg19/vgg19_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5: None -- [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Comment: Did you try running the code again? It seems a temporary problem in the internet connection

Comment: I did that several times and tried different strategies before posting it here. Still, it didn't work

Comment: I insist, there was a Google outage a few hours ago, the URL works fine for me, this is a local problem with your or the servers' internet connection.

Comment: I have just tried it again. It's same. Don't know if it's my location.

Comment: It just worked. I am using kaggle. I just went to the settings tab on the right, confirmed my phone number and put on the internet option. I don't know what that settings did but it worked just fine. I have been using the internet and uploading data on kaggle. Don't know what happened